# Control how long an animation would last in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, android-animation

I want to control the number of seconds an animation would run in my application,
but i found only two options - infinite run or one-shot run, and i want the animation to run more than once but with an end - i.e: the animation talk, and I want that in some point, the mouth will stop moving.

this is my animation-list xml:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/combi_animation" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/combi_logo" android:duration="600" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/combi_mouth_closed" android:duration="600" />
</animation-list>
```

and my animation code:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;
    ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.combi_icon);
    rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.combi_animation);
    rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
    rocketAnimation.start();
}
```

I thought that maybe there could be a listener, that would stop the animation after an amount of time
decided by me. I mean, after 10 seconds the animation would stop.
But I could not find a proper way to do so. How can It be done?

Comment: can you simply use `clearAnimation()` on whichever view you have applied it after your particular timer ?

Comment: the timer is exactly my problem - i could not understand how to do the waiting thing before i ended the animation in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                rocketAnimation.stop();
            }
        },10*1000);
```